# How to do yarn add command w/o adding auto-upgrade version modifier to package.json?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, package.json

What's the correct option for calling `yarnpkg v2+` to add the latest package version to `package.json` BUT without auto-upgrade modifier (^-sign).

AS IS:

`yarn add luxon`

package.json:

```
{
  "luxon": "^2.3.1"
}
```

TO BE:

package.json:

`yarn add <some option here?> luxon`

```
{
  "luxon": "2.3.1"
}
```

What I have to do?
Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--exact/-E` option

Using `--exact` or `-E` installs the packages as exact versions.

```
yarn add luxon --exact
```